# How to change liferay language properties file in hook

Tags: liferay, liferay-hook

I've added a few items to the registration portal. Now I want to label them for the specific language. Liferay like.

in liferay hook :

```
<hook>
     <language-properties>content/Language_en.properties</language-properties>
     <language-properties>content/Language_fa.properties</language-properties>
</hook>
```

and in Language_en.properties :

```
 educationType= Education Type
 mobileNumber =Mobile Number
```

and in Language_fa.properties :

```
 educationType= persian education type 
 mobileNumber = persian  Mobile Number.
```

and   craete_account.jsp

```
  <aui:input name="educationType" type="text"></aui:input>
  <aui:input label="Mobile Number" name="mobileNumber" type="tel"> </aui:input>
```

now, which way should i use to label these 2 items

Comment: Are you developing a custom plugin? or using a liferay plugin? can you also tell us about the Liferay version you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, import the `ui` taglib at the top of your page like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>
```

Then use the `ui:message` tag to render the appropriate label, passing in the correct key for that label, like this:

```
<liferay-ui:message key="educationType" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow this link to create Language.properties hook:

http://proliferay.com/liferay-language-properties-hook-development/